# Using evil-leader with use-package: Error (use-package): evil-leader/:config: Invalid function: (global-evil-leader-mode)

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs, evil-mode

I'm trying to add `use-package` to my `init.el` and I'm running into this error:

`Error (use-package): evil-leader/:config: Invalid function: (global-evil-leader-mode)`

Here's a stripped down `init.el` that produces that error (assumes evil and evil-leader are already installed)

```
(package-initialize)

(require 'use-package)

(use-package evil :ensure)

(use-package evil-leader
  :ensure
  :after evil
  :config
  ((global-evil-leader-mode)
      (evil-leader/set-leader ",")
      (evil-leader/set-key
        "b" 'buffer-menu)
      ; Apparently this needs to go after (global-evil-leader-mode)
      ; https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30332/evil-leader-stops-working-when-i-eval-buffer
      (evil-mode t)))
```

This is how it was set up without `use-package` working correctly:

```
(package-initialize)

(require 'evil)

(require 'evil-leader)
(global-evil-leader-mode)
(evil-leader/set-leader ",")
(evil-leader/set-key
  "b" 'buffer-menu)
; Apparently this needs to go after (global-evil-leader-mode)
; https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30332/evil-leader-stops-working-when-i-eval-buffer
(evil-mode t)
```

Any help identifying what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thin you should remove the parenthesis after `:config`

Comment: Thanks! If I only do (global-evil-leader-mode) this does work. I have multiple functions I want to run after config though, how would I rewrite this so that I can run all of them?

Comment: Just having `:config (fun1 ...) (fun2 ...) (fun3 ...)` should work (they all get executed sequentially after the package is loaded). Does this give you an error?

Comment: Yeah that looks like it works, thank you!